# When putting a watch on a breakpoint, Java debugger shows a boxed Integer instead of primitive int

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, java-8, default-method

This simple example demonstrates the problem:

```
public class Main {
    interface Person {
        default int amountOfHands() {
            return 2;
        }
    }

    public static class BasicPerson implements Person {

        int numberOfFaces() {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Put a breakpoint here");
    }
}
```

I ran this code in IntelliJ IDEA in debug mode and put two watches in the main method:

```
new BasicPerson().amountOfHands();

new BasicPerson().numberOfFaces();
```

Both methods should return a primitive int, however only the second watch (class method) shows a primitive int, when the first one (default interface method) shows a boxed Integer object.

[image: Watches]

Why is that? Is that a bug?

Answer (score 4):

I suppose it's a bug in IntelliJ IDEA. In Eclipse both expressions are evaluated to primitive values as expected.